# cannot get CBitmap displayed on Picture Control

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi

I am trying to display a jpeg file on picture control first I load it using GDIpluse then I convert it to CBitmap after that I tried to put it on Picture control named `m_picture_control` which is defined as CStatic on my Dialog but it cannot be displayed

```
Bitmap* pBitmap = Bitmap::FromFile(FileDlg.GetPathName());
    Status status = pBitmap->GetLastStatus();
    if(Ok == status)
    {
       HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
       status = pBitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color(0,0,0), &hBitmap);
       if(Ok == status)
       {
           CBitmap* bitmap = new CBitmap();
          bitmap->Attach(hBitmap);
          m_picture_control.SetBitmap(*bitmap);
       }
```

Comment: Did you create the CStatic with the `SS_BITMAP` style? (Properties->Type: Bitmap)

Comment: yeah  you are right ! that was the problem

Comment: This seems to have been resolved.  Voting to close.